# Get return code of bash script run by ShellExecuteExA C++

Tags: c++, winapi

I've got some shell scripts I'm running using **[ShellExecuteExA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shellexecuteexa)**. I ping for the exit code once per second using **[GetGetExitCodeProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-getexitcodeprocess)** but it only returns `0` or `STILL_ACTIVE` for obvious reasons.

I need to get the exit code of the bash script that is running in the shell. The C++ program is single threaded, so I can't have a blocking solution since I need other stuff to run while the shell is doing its thing.

Is there any solution to get that exit code without resorting to overhauling large parts of my program to make it multithreaded?

Answer (score -1):

If you're using `ShellExecuteExA` to run a shell script from your C++ program, you won't be able to directly obtain the exit code of the script using `GetExitCodeProcess`. This is because `ShellExecuteExA` launches a separate process to execute the script, and `GetExitCodeProcess` is designed to retrieve the exit code of a child process created by your own program.

To obtain the exit code of the script, you have a few alternative options:

1. Use `CreateProcess` instead of `ShellExecuteExA`: Instead of using `ShellExecuteExA`, you can use the `CreateProcess` function to run the shell script. `CreateProcess` allows you to retrieve the process handle, which you can later use with `GetExitCodeProcess` to obtain the exit code.
2. Use a pipe to capture the exit code: You can modify your shell script to output the exit code to a file or pipe, and then have your C++ program read the exit code from that file or pipe after the script execution completes. This would require modifying both the C++ program and the shell script.
3. Use a wrapper script: Create a wrapper shell script that runs your original script and outputs the exit code. Modify your C++ program to run the wrapper script instead of the original script, and capture the exit code from the wrapper script's output.
4. Use a separate thread or process: If modifying your C++ program to be multithreaded is not feasible, you can create a separate thread or process that monitors the execution of the shell script and retrieves the exit code. This way, your main program can continue running while the separate thread/process handles the script execution and exit code retrieval.

These options provide different approaches to obtaining the exit code of the shell script without significantly overhauling your existing single-threaded C++ program. Choose the option that best fits your requirements and constraints.

Comment: You can do it with ShellExecuteEx by asking for a process handle. But I wouldn't recommend it. CreateProcess is the right way.